# Powershell not compiling c# code into .exe

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have some code that is not compiling to an .exe file in PowerShell,

```
  $csharp = '#CSharp code goes here'
  $tmpFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + ".cs" # Creates Temp file
  Out-file -FilePath $tmpFile -InputObject $csharp # sets content
  Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -ArgumentList "/out:Launcher.exe" # Starts csc
```

When the script loads there is a popup with csc.exe that closes within milliseconds.
Could anyone help? Thanks, CollinScripter

Comment: I don't see how you are specifying that tmp file into the csc command, you are just expecting an output with no input.   Also add a bugreport to see the error.   `"/addmodule:$tmpFile /out:Launcher.exe bugreport:c:\WhyItFailed.txt`  Try that and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works better once you add an input.  I generated a `fatal error CS2008: No inputs specified` with your snippet.

```
  $csharp = '#CSharp code goes here'
  $tmpFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + ".cs" # Creates Temp file
  Out-file -FilePath $tmpFile -InputObject $csharp # sets content

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -ArgumentList "/addmodule:$tmpFile /out:Launcher.exe" # Starts csc
```

Comment: Now I get an corrupt file error. fatal error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Users\CollinScripter\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1795.cs' could not be opened -- 'File is
        corrupt.'

Comment: Might be in the $csharp variable, are you sure it is a fully functioning c# app.  Does the .cs temp file match the output desired (open with notepad.exe)

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -ArgumentList "/out:Launcher.exe $tmpFile" # Starts csc`   If that fixes it, I will edit answer.

Comment: c:\Users\CollinScripter\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD546.cs(2,13): error C
S0116: A namespace
        cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\Users\CollinScripter\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD546.cs(3,24): error CS1518: Expected class,
        delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Comment: Don't know really how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the new window from appearing you can use the `NoNewWindow` switch:

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "/out:Launcher.exe"
```

Note your current command is not passing the source file to compile.